# Removing CIS Level 2 RH profile from Rocky Linux 9

Tags: linux, rocky-linux, openscap

I have selected the Redhat CIS server level security profile while installation and now I am seeing lot of restriction. I like to remove this security profile from my Rocky Linux 9.

I have tested the Openscap scan and its onlt 62% pass while having Above security profile.

please let me know how to remove or add security profile after instalation.

Regards
Arvind

Answer (score 0):

When you select a profile during the installation of RHEL (or a step child), the installer will use [oscap-anaconda-addon][1] and apply remediations of that profile to the install. That's all - and I don't think that profile is used later to re-assert the system install.

This approach exists because there are several policy items that cannot be remediated post installation only during the initial installation.

However, the compliance to the given profile will be a function of the profile completeness in terms of remediation rules being present in the build. (Also, I wonder whether the profile actually remediates on Rocky, as in the past RHEL clones haven't payed close attention to keep SCAP profiles working).

> please let me know how to remove or add security profile after installation.

There is no way to remove or add the profile. The installation have been amended by the security profile, and you are welcome to re-install if you no longer like that.